# xlCellTypeVisible not returning filtered range, instead whole range

Tags: vba, excel

okay folks, totally baffled here...

I have a linked table in Excel from Access. I am trying to write a **vba function that returns the filtered range address** of a given column of that table. Bear in mind that I am trying to stick with structured references (for example, Table1[[#Data],[Column2]] ) since it's a linked table and is designed to refresh and change over time.

I am using **xlCellTypeVisible** with no avail. The function still returns the whole range, even though it is filtered.

Further confusing is I created a nearly identical Sub (instead of Function so I can step through) which *is* correctly returning the desired return! I stumped; I just can't duplicate it in the Function. I suspect it has something to do with the structured references.

The function "filteredRange" incorrectly returns the whole range "$F$2:$F74" when I enter *this* into any cell in Excel.

```
=filteredRange(Table_RyanDB[[#Data],[LC]])
```

Whereas the following Sub "test" does returns the correct answer "$F$2:$F$14". I can't seem to discern why they're not outputting the same with the input variable is identical.

```
Sub test()
    Dim theRange As Range
    Set theRange = Range("Table_RyanDB[[#Data],[LC]]")
    MsgBox theRange.Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Address
End Sub



Function filteredRange(theRange As Range)
    filteredRange = theRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Address
End Function
```

Answer (score 5):

Excel UDF has some [limitations](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/170787) and `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` not working propertly here. Use this one instead:

```
Function filteredRange(theRange As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim r As Range

    For Each r In theRange.Rows
        If Not r.Hidden Then
            If rng Is Nothing Then
                Set rng = r
            Else
                Set rng = Union(rng, r)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then filteredRange = rng.Address
End Function
```

Comment: I'm curious, how do the udf limitations affect OP's code?

Comment: @ckuhn203 `.SpecialCells` is a method of a range object, and although it doesn't say *which* methods are affected, per documentation, "most" methods can't be executed.